# Diferenecia de Serializable() y Parcelable()

Tags: android

No entiendo muy bien el uso de `Parcelable()` y `Serializable()`.

¿Cual es la diferencia entre `Serializable()` y un `Parcelable()`?

¿En que casos puedo usar un `Parcelable` y en cuales un `Serializable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)**, es mucho más rápido que Serializable ya que esta optimizado para su uso en Android, la interfaz creada por Google es [android.os.Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/package-summary.html), en cuanto a la implementación probablemente te tome más tiempo comparado con Serializable, pero obtendrás mejores beneficios.

**[Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)**, es más lenta comparada con Parcelable. Usa la interfaz [estandar de java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) , por esta razón su implementación es más  sencilla comparada con Parcelable. Una característica importante es que un arreglo Parcelable puede ser enviado mediante un intent en Android. Una caracteristica no favorable puede ser que Serializable crea muchos objetos en memoria, aunque son temporales puede causar un poco de [Garbage Collecting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recolector_de_basura).

Si estas desarrollando en Android como indica tu pregunta la opción es usar **[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)**

Agrego una tabla comparativa de pruebas donde puedes comparar la velocidad de ambas interfaces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fuente: **[Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)** (inglés)

Answer (score 4):

Lo mejor de `Serializable()` es que solo se necesita la interfaz y Java se ocupa de hacerlo lo mejor que puede.

Con `Parcelable()` te irá mejor en android, puesto que es mucho más rápido y eficiente ya que está hecho específicamente para Android.

Te dejo un poco de información que te acabará de ayudar ;) 
http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/